# To get the created datetime and created by for Security role assigned to user in AX 2012

Tags: sql-server, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

Is it possible to get **CreatedDateTime** and **Createdby** for the **security** **role** added to the **user** through sql query

This is query used to get the Security role

```
select distinct a.id as username , a.NAME Name, f.Text [Role] 
from userinfo a (nolock)  join securityuserrole b (nolock) on a.id=b.user_      
join SECURITYUSERROLECONDITION c (nolock) on b.recid = c.securityuserrole       
join  [Dynamics_STG_model].[dbo].[ModelSecurityRole] e (nolock) on e.rolehandle = b.securityrole        
join [Dynamics_STG_model].[dbo].[ModelElementLabel] f (nolock)  on e.LABELID = f.LabelId and e.LABELMODULE = f.Module and f.Language='en_us'
```

Please help me regarding this.
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the answer by myself:

```
Declare @StartDate datetime 
Declare @EndDate datetime 
Set @StartDate = '2015-07-07 01:31:38.000' 
Set @EndDate = '2015-08-21 01:14:14.000' 
Set @StartDate = convert(datetime, dateadd(hour, 7, @StartDate), 100) 
Set @EndDate = convert(datetime, dateadd(hour, 7, @EndDate), 100)

select distinct a.NAME [User Name]
               ,b.USERNAME [Role Modified By]
               ,convert(datetime, dateadd(hour, -7, b.CREATEDDATETIME), 100) [Modified DateTime]
               ,case b.LOGTYPE 
                   when 0 then 'Added'
                   when 1 then 'Removed' 
                end as Status
               ,d.Text Role 
from USERINFO a (nolock) 
join(
    select (case when logtype = 0 then dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 16) AS varbinary(8000)), 2)
                 when logtype = 1 then dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 10) AS varbinary(8000)), 2)           
            end) AS UserNam
           ,USERNAME
           ,CREATEDDATETIME
           ,logtype
           ,(case when logtype = 0 then dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 15) AS varbinary(8000)), 2)
                  when logtype = 1 then dbo.CONPEEK(CAST(dbo.CONPEEK(data, 9) AS varbinary(8000)), 2) 
             end) as SecurityRole    
    from SYSDATABASELOG (nolock) where TABLE_=65492 and data !='')  b  
on a.id = b.UserNam 
left outer join [DynamicsAX_model].[dbo].[modelsecurityrole] c (nolock) on b.SecurityRole =c.rolehandle 
join [modelelementlabel] d (nolock) on c.labelid = d.labelid 
                                   and c.LABELMODULE = d.module 
                                   and d.Language='en_us' 
where b.CREATEDDATETIME >= @StartDate and b.CREATEDDATETIME <=@EndDate order by [Modified DateTime] desc
```

**Conpeek** and **consize** are two functions we need to create from the below link  download [ConPeek.sql](http://dax.codemann8.com/downloads/Container2SQL/ConPeek.sql) and [ConSize.sql](http://dax.codemann8.com/downloads/Container2SQL/ConSize.sql)

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [database logging](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd362089.aspx) for table `SecurityUserRole` (System → Security user role).

Comment: In SQL -> sysdatabase log, field DATA, it is varbinary, while converting it to varchar it shows ýý something like this. 

If i'm able to convert this then i'm able to see the value

While running Database log report, i can see user's role added datetime
i need through sql

please advice.

Comment: Field `Data` contains a container, you can check `\Data Dictionary\Maps\LogMap\Methods\getDataAsList` to get an understanding how data is stored there. If you need a SQL Server solution (as opposed to an AX solution) then you can check whether Change Data Capture can serve your needs: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489%28v=sql.105%29.aspx (although I doubt you'll be able to see CreatedBy username this way).

Comment: http://abraaxapta.blogspot.com/2011/06/accessing-dynamics-ax-containers-from.html From the above link, i had found to get data from the container, it is not working fine larger data in SQL